# Intellij 14 Grails Project Error on run-app: Module not backed by Gradle

Tags: grails, intellij-14

I recently downloaded a new Intellij version 2017 for Grails 3 upgrade .I am using Intellij 14 with Grails 2.3.7.When I was prompted to import settings for new version,I clicked yes .Now however when I try to run my existing 2.3.7 project in Intellij 14 ,it complains Module not backed by gradle. I did not use gradle in my 2.3.7 Project.How to run this app.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my project.iml file was messed up.I had to clean that up and was able run in previous version.Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ./gradlew command with gradle installed in your machine to rebuild your gradle project.